# SQL Server Instance not started after fresh installation of SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have tried to install MS SQL Server Developer 2019 (free) edition.
The installation finished without any errors. I also installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.
But the issue is that the SQL Server Instance has not been correctly configured somehow because the service is not started.

I find that there are no running instances in SSCM!

[image]

Please guide on what can be missing.
I doubt on Firewall warning (I am not able to turn off firewall due to McAffee Personal Security).
I did not disable firewall, and proceeded setup.

Please note that I followed the steps exactly as per below link:-
[Installing SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition](https://jimsalasek.com/2019/12/03/installing-sql-server-2019-developer-edition/)

Please someone help on why Server instance is not starting and comment if any additional details are needed.

Comment: That image suggests that you have *not* installed SQL Server.

Comment: what about windows services? Are there any sqlserver related services? Have you had earlier versions installed? Earlier versions of configuration manager are not forward compatible.

Comment: @lptr I can see only 'SQL Server Browser' and 'SQL Server VSS Writer" services. I have done fresh installation of Developer edition. There were no previous versions of Configuration manager on my machine. Clearly, I am missing something. Please can you check the installation link, and point to what steps are missing there? I got no errors while installation, that's why I am clueless.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally unticked the "Database Engine Services" checkbox on the "Feature Selection" page of the setup wizard. You should run through the setup wizard again and make sure that option is ticked - you can run the setup wizard many times to add/remove items. Also two things to try: 1) Turn off your anti-virus software while installing, and 2) when starting the setup.exe program right-click on it and select "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the exact same situation. Running through a manual installation does show the 'Database Engine' (SQLENGINE) feature. This was the same result using same media on other servers in other environments. I suspect something defective in the media.

I had to install the Express Edition and 'upgrade' to Developer edition.

KR,Tim GJ

Comment: Sorry, correction - 'does NOT show the 'Database Engine' feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the Developer Edition directory and run SETUP.EXE then select the  Installation -> New SQL Server standalone installation, and follow the instructions.

[image: installation]